# CSS styles broken after updating Active Admin 0.6.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin, gemfile

I was wondering if anyone might have some experience with this:

I updated `Active Admin 0.6.0` (and four dependencies), and now the stylesheets aren't loading properly in the app, (broken on my machine and on staging)

Here's the list of gems (versions) with brief explanations

```
Installing activeadmin (0.6.3)
Installing kaminari (0.15.1)
Installing has_scope (0.6.0.rc)
Installing responders (1.0.0)
Installing inherited_resources (1.4.1)

Removing activeadmin (0.6.0) administration framework for Ruby on Rails
Removing kaminari (0.14.1)   paginator for frameworks and orms
Removing has_scope (0.5.1)   create controller folters based on your resources named scopes
Removing responders (0.9.3)  a set of responders to dry rails 3.2+
Removing inherited_resources (1.4.0)  make controllers inherit all restful actions
```

**The offending commit only edited Gemfile and Gemfile.lock.**  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe you need to run a `rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: Where is the styles broken? in ActiveAdmin or your App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity:
The css problems were due to a css bug in Active Admin 0.6.0.  Since I *started* with Active Admin 0.6.0, I unknowingly wrote my css to compensate for the bug, then when the bug was removed in 0.6.1, my css broke.  Had I started on any other version of Active Admin, this wouldn't have happened.
When I finally upgraded past 0.6.0, I also had to fix my css.

Answer (score 0):

Try precompiling the assests with the following command.
rake asset:precompile